# How to create a new postgresql database via ubuntu shell

Tags: postgresql, bash

I’m doing;

```
createdb -O dan -h 127.0.1.1 -p 5432 -U dan -w testdb
```

but it throws me:

> `fe_sendauth: no password supplied`

Then I tried to remove `-w` and it asks for a password but no one password that I type matches:

> `password authentication failed for user "dan"`

Also it should be a bash script, so I can`t enter psql (I guess). Thank you

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yeah, well, I tried same command with 'postgres' instead of 'dan'. But it still asks for a password (standart password 'postgres' doesn`t match).

Comment: Are you sure that you know the password of user postgres of this instance, not the OS user postgres. if you know it try this  PGPASSWORD="<postgres_password>" createdb -O dan -h 127.0.1.1 -p 5432 -U postgres testdb

Comment: @AdelinoSilva same error. Had I set password for postgres user manuanly in very begining? 'createdb testdb' as postgres user works perfectly and this db belongs postgres.

Comment: Whether a password is required depends on your settings in pg_hba.conf. And there are different ways you can connect - different settings in pg_hba.conf may apply.